# A Gaussian process with $E(X_t-X_0)^2\sim\vert \log t\vert^{-\beta}$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, positive-definite, gaussian

Exercise  6.1 (Section 4.5) in: An Introduction to Continuity, Extrema, and Related Topics for General Gaussian Processes by R. Adler starts:

> Let $X_t$ be a stationary Gaussian process on $[0,1]$ and assume $E(X_t-X_0)^2 \sim  \vert \log t\vert^{-\beta}$, $\beta>0$.

I have two questions

1. Do you know what does the $\sim$ symbol means? My guess is that this means that $E(X_t-X_0)^2$ can be upper and lower bounded by positive constants times $\vert \log t\vert^{-\beta}$
2. Why such a Gaussian process exists? Of course I know this is related with the positive definiteness of the covariance functions.

Comment: 1. The usual meaning of $f(t)\sim g(t) $ is that $\lim_t f(t)/g(t) =1$,  in this case (I presume) as $t\to+\infty$.

Comment: I guess in this case is $t\uparrow 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As mentioned in the comments, this should mean that $E(X_t-X_0)^2/\vert \log t\vert^{-\beta}\to 1$, but, of course, as $t\to 0$, not $\infty$ or $1$.
2. A stationary Gaussian process can be constructed by means of a moving average representation:
   $$
   X_t = \int_{-\infty}^t f(t-s) dW_s
   $$
   with $W$ being a standard Wiener process and some $f\in L^2(0,\infty)$. Then one needs to find $f$ such that $$E(X_t-X_0)^2 = \int_0^t f(u)^2 du + \int_{0}^\infty |f(u) - f(u+t)|^2 dt \sim \vert \log t\vert^{-\beta}, t\to 0+.$$
   This is an easy exercise, but please write if you will have any problems with this.